# How to use a custom script in django models

Tags: django, django-models

Here are my files :

```
+Price
++models.py
+Scripts
++Analyse.py
```

I would like to use Analyse.py in my models for the save().

But when i tried in `models.py`

```py
from Script.Analyse import test
```

it doesn't work, and i can't put it in the `Price` Folder this script will be used for other app.

any idea anyone ?

Regards and thanks

Comment: Have you included `Scripts` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` ?

Comment: Also avoid the uppercases…

Answer (score 0):

You need to clearly understand difference between **folder** and **python package.**
Python package should have

> --init--.py //replace with underscrores

So if you planning to write a package Scripts
you will need to have something like this:

scripts
++**init**.py
++myfunctions.py

and in myfunctions.py you can have

```
#example function
def donothing():
++++pass
#so now you can use your scripts like this
from yourapp.scripts import donothing
if (1==1):
++++donothing()
```